# Let $R$ be an integral domain, $M$ is free $R$-module with finite basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be an integral domain, $M$ is free $R$-module with finite basis. Prove that two finite bases of $M$ have the same cardinality.

Help me some hints.

Comment: @user: Can you tell me such textbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ commutative ring then there is morphism $f:R\rightarrow k$ on to some field $k$. Suppose $R^n=R^m$ for some $n, m\in \mathbb N$. $k^m=(R/\ker f)^m=(R\otimes R/\ker f)^m=R^m\otimes R/\ker f=R^n\otimes R/\ker f=(R\otimes R/\ker f)^n$ $=(R/\ker f)^n=k^n$.

Its easy to see that $R$ module $k\cong R/\ker f$ has $k$ module structure. We reduced our problem to the fact that two vector spaces has bases of the same cardinality and in this case we know that $n=m$.